# Sitecore webforms for marketers and workflow

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-workflow

I'm creating a Sitecore item with the web forms for marketers module. The item has a default workflow defined on the standard values. The expected behavior when I save the form is the item being automatically inserted in the default workflow, instead the new item is created but not inserted in any workflow.

Is there a way I can include the item in the workflow automatically, or to create a custom action that will detect the item being saved and sets its workflow up?

I would like to avoid creating a custom action myself to duplicate the create item plus workflow. I really like the fact that the advanced users can create their save actions and field mapping themselves, and I will lose that feature if I had to create a custom action for every new template needing an entry form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague tried to add workflow to WFFM forms recently, and discovered that you cannot. We filed this with Sitecore support and we've been told it has been forwarded to the product team.

Unfortunately, this means that advanced users that edit a form are directly editing the approved version of a form, and there is no way to create a 'draft' version.

The support portal seems to be down right now, so I can't extract the ticket number, but I'll update this once I can.

**Update:** This issue is logged from us as ticket #405553. It's currently 'closed' due to inactivity, but if you reference it Sitecore should be able to track down the current status with the product team.

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow up with sitecore

Comment: What about an alternative approach: If know the target location plus the template and if I know that all the items at that location with that specific template must have a workflow, then I can create an action that scans the target location and assign workflows to items without any workflow...

Comment: It's not a matter of assigning workflow. From what I understand, the Form Designer wizard bypasses the workflow applied to items does not act in the security context of the user. This means it edits the current version instead of creating a new version to go through workflow, regardless of whether it was in workflow or not.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being a bit late to the party. We've encountered this error and managed to resolve it for a sitecore 7.1 site

We found that the item created by WFFM would have a workflow assigned to it if the website had the LiveMode.config included in the website. Live mode for 7.1 sets "enableWorkflow" to true for the site "website".

Adding this setting into the site node e.g.

```
<site name="website" enableworkflow="true" etc etc etc/>
```

Hopefully when you try this it should work (make sure you **exclude** the LiveMode.config)